# ABAP making HTTPS requests to REST service

Tags: abap

Is it possible to make HTTPS requests to a REST service from an ABAP program?

I'm about to start into a project which requires a call from an SAP instance to a remotely hosted service using XML over HTTPS. Does anyone have sample ABAP code?

Comment: Which product do you mean? SAP R/3 with ECC Core, XI/PI or any other of the various systems they sell?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a SDN article titled "[Real Web Services with REST and ICF](http://www.sdn.sap.com/irj/scn/go/portal/prtroot/docs/library/uuid/ea8db790-0201-0010-af98-de15b6c1ee1a)". This covers the server side (providing a REST service) only, but maybe this could help you getting started. There's also the (arguably rather concise) [documentation on client side ICF development](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw04/helpdata/en/36/020d3a0154b909e10000000a114084/frameset.htm). However, it looks like you'll have to parse the body on your own, using nothing but the XML support SAP provides you with. That's the drawback of REST...

Comment: That's useful info, but mostly refers to SOAP style implementations. We have a similar problem, but the stumbling blocks are that SAP doesn't appear to support setting any HTTP verb except POST and that it doesn't have a JSON deserialiser.

Answer (score 3):

This can be done using `cl_http_client`.
Check the [SAP help documentation](https://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw74/helpdata/en/b2/86b4512ea4414fb36f17b0568a86ac/content.htm) for the code.

For making HTTPS calls, you also need to import the certificate of your service provider into the system. This can be done using the transaction "STRUST".   This step is compulsory; without it, you`ll get communication errors.