# HTTPS certificate for Google Maps

Tags: api, rest, https, abap

I read that request [SAP making HTTPS requests to REST service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2245345/sap-making-https-requests-to-rest-service) and is written : "For making HTTPS calls, you also need to import the certificate of your service provider into the system".
But what means with "service provider"? Who is the service provider in this context?

I have to make HTTPS calls to google maps using ABAP, but now it's not allowed to do it without API-KEY, I need to use HTTPS.

Answer (score 2):

Your service provider is google for your maps api. You need to install google SSL certificate to SAP with STRUST t-code. Also HTTPS must be enabled for using it. Check below for example guideline:

https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/SWAPI/Importing+StreamWork+SSL+certificate+into+ABAP+systems